# Use any member of a string union in a template literal at most once

Tags: typescript

I have a union of 3 possible strings:

```
type AllowedWords = "one" | "two" | "three";
```

I want to create a template literal type that allows any of those 3 words in any order, but each member should only be included up to once. For example, this should be an exhaustive list of all possible matches:

- `one`
- `two`
- `three`
- `onetwo`
- `onethree`
- `twoone`
- `twothree`
- `threeone`
- `threetwo`
- `onetwothree`
- `onethreetwo`
- `twoonethree`
- `twothreeone`
- `threeonetwo`
- `threetwoone`

How can I define a type that represents that?

Comment: Yeah I was going to point to that one too... you can do something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N71EBW) but oh boy does it get unwieldy quickly

Comment: @Nenad this allows duplicate elements. The linked answer does not and the question mentions *"each member should only be included up to once"*. Also, if you believe there is a better answer to a question, you should post the better answer as an answer to the older post. But duplicate questions should be closed as duplicates.

Comment: @TobiasS. OK, I see the difference related to the *duplicate elements*. However, original question and answer are noisy and less readable, that's where I'm not sure if this should have been deleted, in favor of the other one.